# FK desconocido en Relaciones Elocuentes en laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Tengo un problema con una consulta en laravel, el query que genera laravel esta haciendo la consulta con una FK que no existe.

Tengo los siguientes modelos

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class KaseyaScope extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'DB_Serverr';
    protected $table = 'adminScope';
    protected $fillable = ['ref'];


    public function pathers(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(KaseyaPatherUser::class,'adminScopeAcl','adminScopeFK','partnerUserFK');
    }
}
```

El otro

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class KaseyaPatherUser extends Model
{
  protected $connection = 'DB_Serverr';
  protected $table = 'partnerUser';
  protected $fillable = ['id','username'];

  public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(KaseyaUser::class);
  }

  public function scopes(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(KaseyaScope::class,'adminScopeAcl','partnerUserFK','adminScopeFK');
  }
```

al otener un KaseyaScope y mostrarlo con dd se ve algo asi

```
KaseyaScope {#274 ▼
  #connection: "DB_Serverr"
  #table: "adminScope"
  #fillable: array:1 [▼
    0 => "ref"
  ]
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:4 [▼
    "id" => "54542471851818725447193731"
    "ref" => "laboratorio"
    "partitionid" => "1"
    "internalCode" => "0"
  ]
  #original: array:4 [▼
    "id" => "54542471851818725447193731"
    "ref" => "laboratorio"
    "partitionid" => "1"
    "internalCode" => "0"
  ]
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #events: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

Entonces lo que quiero hacer es obtener todos los pathers de ese kaseyaScope y lo hace con lo siguiente **$scope->pathers** pero me devuelve un null cuando deveria devolverme un pathers que en la base de datos existe:

Esta es la tabla que relaciona los pather con los scopes ya que es una relación muchos a muchos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Entonces como se que existe una realcion por al hacer la consulta no me devuelve nada, **recurro a generar un error** 
cambiando una linea del modelo de KaseyaScope quedando asi

```
return $this->belongsToMany(KaseyaPatherUser::class,'adminScopeAcl','adminScopeFK','partnerUserFKR');
```

Le agregue un R a la llave foranea y el error que genera es

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 207 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [207] (severity 16) [(null)] (SQL: select [partnerUser].*, [adminScopeAcl].[adminScopeFK] as [pivot_adminScopeFK], [adminScopeAcl].[partnerUserFKR] as [pivot_partnerUserFKR] from [partnerUser] inner join [adminScopeAcl] on [partnerUser].[id] = [adminScopeAcl].[partnerUserFKR] where [adminScopeAcl].[adminScopeFK] = 9223372036854775807)
```

Básicamente la consulta "esta bien" el unico problema es que el valor 9223372036854775807 no se de donde lo tima si ese valor no existe en ninguna de las 3 tablas, ni en **adminScopeAcl** ni en **partnerUser** ni en **adminScope**

Campos de las 3 tablas

Tabla de adminScopeAcl

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
tabla de adminScope

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
tabla de partnerUser

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien que me ayuda a saber de donde sale ese valor 9223372036854775807 en la consulta, el cual me esta poniendo un FK que no existe y por eso mo lo devuelve en null

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que ese id se alimentaba de otra base de datos hecha en SQL server al parecer el php tiene que ser de 64bits para soporte ese tipo de ids tan largo asi que la solucion fue dejar un id autoincremental y crear una columna donde se almacena el id largo.